# MikTeX - I can't find how to get design view - two panels on screen

Tags: latex, miktex

I am using MikTeX Studio to work on a LaTeX file.

How can I set it up so that I get the code in a left hand panel and the print (pdf) view in the right hand panel?

I do get this after an edit but I would like it set this way all of the time.

I appreciate any help that anyone can give.

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit then preferences. And select this option to show the pdf after compiling. This should work.

After you compiled the pdf stays there.